# geopandas plot a polygon on a existing figure

Tags: geopandas

I have a plot of dataframe and I would like to continue plotting a polygon, but I get the message `Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes`

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

ax1 = stopvu_count.plot.scatter(x='lon', y= 'lat')
polygonY = Polygon([(37.991920,23.731388),
                    (37.991771,23.731337),
                    (37.991181,23.735570),
                    ])
p1 = gpd.GeoSeries(polygonY)
p1.plot(facecolor="none",edgecolor='black',ax=ax1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: what is stopvu_count? is that the dataframe?

Comment: @Mel Yes. I may need to close this question. The problem mentioned happens when I run the two plot command in two seperate cell in Jupyter. If I run them in one cell, the result is right. I am not sure why.

Comment: Do you just want to be able to plot the polygon itself?
have you tried something like this? 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
p1.plot(ax=ax, facecolor = 'red')
plt.tight_layout();